# Reprojecting Openlayers plugin layers

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have shapefiles containing coordinate system WGS84, when i try to upload google satellite from Open Layers Plugin, it automatically changes its coordinate system to WGS84/world mercator EPS3395 (the  projected one) but fits exactly in the same position, but when i try to change its coordinated system its position got miss matched, the same thing happens when i try to do compose a map or/and export it as data

I am really new to QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the layer seems to be fitting despite being with another CRS is because of "On the fly" projection tool. You can have a look at QGis documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#define-on-the-fly-otf-crs-transformation) for more details.

As the data given by Open Layers is given by web api (cf. [official repo](https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin)), I don't think you can easily change the CRS. That's why the "OTF" tool is here, to reproject the layers even if your data layers are not in the same projection than the google ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Open Layers Plugin will do that.  Alternatively, the Quick Map Services plugin (http://nextgis.com/blog/quickmapservices/) is a spectacular improvement, and is quite flexible and forgiving in regards to coordinate systems.  I don't have access to QGIS at the moment, but I recall that you have to enable experimental plugins in the plugin manager in order to see and then enable QMS in the plugin list.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are so many web-resources still referring to the OpenLayers Plugin for usage in QGIS. I didn't touch it for years because of the unreliable outcome and many quirks in map production. The QuickMapServices plugin at the moment is THE way to go. To get all possible sources, you will have to get the "contributed pack" in the plugins settings.

Then you have the possibility to use the basemaps in every CRS you wish. Keep in mind that labels in such layers will be distorted then, cause they were produced to align with the web mercator projection.